# Scale the output of movie() before playing the movie

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure

I'm trying to create a `movie()` of a flickering checkerboard in matlab. I'm using the following code to create the frames:

```
close all;

n=80; % length of checkerboard squares in pixels
p=5; % number of checkerboard rows
q=6; % number of checkerboard columns
loops=100;

A=zeros(p*n,q*n,2);
my_checkerboard=logical(checkerboard(n,p,q));
A(:,:,1)=double(my_checkerboard(1:p*n,1:q*n));
A(:,:,2)=ones(p*n,q*n);
%A(:,:,2)=double(~my_checkerboard(1:p*n,1:q*n));
F(loops)=struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);

h=figure;
for ii=1:1000
    figure(h);
    imshow(A(:,:,mod(ii,2)+1));
    drawnow;
    F(ii)=getframe;
end
```

Now if I'm playing the movie like this

```
close all;
h=figure;
movie(h,F,1,10)
```

I will be able to scale the movie by drawing the corners of the figure. But if I'm scaling the figure before like this

```
close all;
h=figure('Position',[2640,280,960,800]);
movie(h,F,1,10)
```

the movie won't be scaled with the figure. Instead the movie will be played in the bottom left corner of the figure.
I got the feeling that this can be done by scaling not just the figure but also the axis, but I couldn't figure out, how to do it.

EDIT: I would also be happy, if someone could link me some resources on a gif generator or something, that can easily create a scalable flickering checkerboard with customizable numbers of tiles.

Comment: Why not setting `n` to larger value?

Comment: @Rotem Because that doesnt work with movie(). Try the code and you‘ll see.

Comment: Try `n=10`, `n = 80`, `n = 200`, and you will see the difference. It stops working when the resolution of `my_checkerboard` is too large, and the figure size is too big to fit the screen.

Comment: @rotem no, it doesnt, just try the code! It works for the imshow, but not fpr the movie. Movie has a set fixed resolution of 560 by 420. see the documentation. So if I set a higher n, the checkerboard will not entirely show in the figure.

Comment: Sorry, I saw the `imshow` part, and didn't wait 1000 frames for the movie part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a bug in MATLAB `movie`...

Following code works in most cases:

```
close all;

n=80; % length of checkerboard squares in pixels
p=5; % number of checkerboard rows
q=6; % number of checkerboard columns
loops=100;

A=zeros(p*n,q*n,2);
my_checkerboard=logical(checkerboard(n,p,q));
A(:,:,1)=double(my_checkerboard(1:p*n,1:q*n));
A(:,:,2)=ones(p*n,q*n);
%A(:,:,2)=double(~my_checkerboard(1:p*n,1:q*n));
F(loops)=struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);

h=figure;
for ii=1:10
    figure(h);
    %imshow(A(:,:,mod(ii,2)+1));
    imshow(A(:,:,mod(ii,2)+1), 'Border', 'tight'); %Show image without borders
    drawnow;
    F(ii)=getframe;
end

savefig(h, 'h.fig') %Save the figure to a file, (not the best solution).

%Playing the movie
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
close all;
h = openfig('h.fig'); %Load the figure

% h=figure;
movie(h,F,1,10)
```

Saving and loading the figure, is just a simple way for keeping the dimensions of the original figure.

Comment: This does indeed work, thanks. Another solution (specifically for my purposes) was to save the checkerboard as a gif instead of using movie(). I'll try to figure out, why saving the figure does work and the other way didn't.